# JNA: Invalid memory access

Tags: java, jna

I've written a small C library that extracts information (a key) from a DLL.

GetKey.h

```
#pragma once

#include <stdint.h>

#define getKey(x) getKeyL(x)
#define getKey(x,y) getKeyP(x,y)

void __declspec(dllexport) getKeyP(char *path, uint8_t key[]);
void __declspec(dllexport) getKeyL(uint8_t key[]);
```

GetKey.c

```
#include "getkey.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

void __declspec(dllexport) getKeyP(char *path, uint8_t key[])
{
    int lib = LoadLibraryA((path != NULL) ? path : "myLib");
    ((void(*)(void))(lib + 0x1340))();
    lib += 0x14020;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        key[i] = *(uint8_t*)(lib + (i << 4));
    }

    FreeLibrary(lib);
}

void __declspec(dllexport) getKeyL(uint8_t key[])
{
    getKeyP(NULL, key);
}
```

My Java binding looks like so:

```
public class GetKey
{
    private static final GetKeyBinding INSTANCE;

    static
    {
        System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "lib/dll/");

        GetKeyBinding lib;

        try
        {
            lib = Native.loadLibrary("x86_64/GetKey.dll", GetKeyBinding.class);
        } 
        catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
        {
            try
            {
                lib = Native.loadLibrary("i386/GetKey.dll", GetKeyBinding.class);
            } 
            catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError f)
            {
                System.err.println("Failed to load library");
                lib = null;
            }
        }

        INSTANCE = lib;
    }

    public static void getKey(byte[] path, byte[] key)
    {
        INSTANCE.getKeyP(path, key);
    }

    public static void getKey(byte[] key)
    {
        INSTANCE.getKeyL(key);
    }

    private static interface GetKeyBinding extends Library
    {
        void getKeyP(byte[] path, byte[] key);
        void getKeyL(byte[] key);
    }
}
```

I get the exception thrown whenever I invoke `getKeyP` and `getKeyL`
I've tried changing the parameter types from `byte[]` to `Pointer` as well as `ByteBuffer`, and I've also tried `extend`ing `StdCallLibrary` (which initially didn't make much sense to me, but it can never hurt to try, can it?) still getting the exception... and I know the code works, because I've written a small test app for it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "GetKey.h"


int main()
{
    uint8_t key[8];
    getKeyP(NULL, key);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        printf("%02X ", key[i]);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

which prints to the console exactly what I'm expecting it to print...
any help is gladly appreciated!

**Edit:**
I'm calling my function from Java like so:

```
byte[] key = new byte[8];
GetKey.getKey(key);
```

Comment: You should take into consideration that `LoadLibrary` can fail. Could you also include how you're calling the function in Java?

Comment: Wouldn't I be getting a NullPointerException in that case? I've tried changing the order in which the code tries loading the DLLs, one, of course, is a 32bit DLL and the other is its 64bit alternative (or perhaps I'm completely off here)

Comment: If `lib == 0`, you would be attempting to call a function at `0x1340`. You would probably get a segmentation fault or illegal memory access.

Answer (score 0):

After attaching a debugger to my DLL and debugging, I discovered that the reason for the exception was "garbage" characters being passed after the intended string.
I fixed this by changing my Java code:

```
public static void getKey(String path, byte[] key)
{
    INSTANCE.getKeyP((path + '\0').getBytes(), key);
}
```

And now it works as intended (-:

Comment: You could just change the first parameter's type to `String`. JNA can marshal it for you.